# Comparing value of nil pointer variable

Tags: go

I know that Go is little different to other languages in this respect, but I wondered if it would be worthwhile for the Go language to automatically test for nil pointers on comparisons and return unequal if only one of the values is nil (in a comparison) rather than creating a run-time error. Go is so great in so many areas I just thought it might do it. The case in point is as follows:

```
type cuForm struct {sName string; iUseCount int64; baForm []byte}

var pugForm *cuForm

//***********************************************************
func loadForm (sWanted string) (*cuForm, os.Error) {
//***********************************************************

    if (sWanted == pugForm.sName) {
```

In the above example, if pugForm is nil, a runtime error occurs. Obviously if only one of the values is nil, it cannot be equal - logically at least. There may well be a reason why this shouldn't be done, but I don't think history should be one reason.

Comment: That's probably better suited at the gonots mailing list

Comment: Only one of *what* values? pugForm isn't a value being compared, it's a pointer to a struct containing the value being compared. If it's nil, it doesn't point to any struct -- it's a program logic error to dereference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is: "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference." The actual error is a nil pointer dereference.

When the pointer pugForm is nil then pugForm.sName is undefined. You want it to be a special value like null in SQL or NaN in floating-point. Now you need a special set of rules for all operations, not just equality.

A nil pointer dereference is almost always wrong. The runtime should object if that happens. If it's not wrong, avoid the problem by testing for nil. Fix your error, don't try to pretend it didn't happen.

What output do you expect from this program?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i int
    var p *int
    var b bool
    b = i == *p
    b = i <= *p
    b = i >= *p
    i += *p
    i -= *p
    i *= *p
    i /= *p
    i %= *p
    i = *p << uint(i)
    i = *p >> uint(i)
    fmt.Println(i, p, b)
}
```

Comment: I think because I referred to comparisons only, the "<" and ">" are not logical (without giving error), and therefore testing for equality is not logical either. Point taken.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying that your question isn't pertinent, I see a good reason to not implement this as the default comportment : that means more tests at runtime and I don't want that for all equality tests of my programs.

But it's true that a dedicated expression (for example something like '===') could (maybe) be useful.

As Nos said, the go-nuts mailing list would probably be a more constructive place for this discussion.

Comment: Even if this was implemented (which I doubt), it would not "break" any existing code, and would not prevent testing for nil. Obviously it could perhaps have unintended consequences (non-errors). Perhaps it would impact runtime to some small extent. It could perhaps improve runtime in some cases by not having to code specifically for it. The thing that makes Go so good (IMHO) is a large number of small improvements and innovations that prevent us saying eternally "why doesn't it allow (or do) this or that?". That to me is what makes it so enjoyable to use - do more with less.

Comment: It would not break a lot of code but it would slow down it. It's interesting but I don't want this new feature to replace my fast existing test.